# I am trying to split string without Split function, but my code doesnt work properly

Tags: c#

I am pretty new to programming this is my first question here.

I am trying to split string (4 names divided by space in my case) and store all the substrings(separate names) to list. But I am not geting the last name (Aaron). Where could be the problem?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CSharp_Shell
{

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string names = "John Martin Sophia Aaron";
            
            
            List<string> namesList = new List<string>();

            string name = "";
            
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                if (names[i] != ' ')
                {
                    name = name + names[i];
                    continue;
                }
            
                    namesList.Add(name);

                    name = "";
            }
            
            foreach(string s in namesList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good example of why it's better to use functions from libraries when they are available. Did you make any effort to debug the code? If not, this is a great opportunity for you to learn how to use a debugger. If you did, please explain what attempt you made and what _specifically_ you need help with. The error in your code is readily apparent to most experienced programmers, but since this looks a lot like homework, you would be better served if you worked out the problem on your own, rather than having it handed to you.

Comment: So when you were stepping through it in the debugger, what became of the last `name`?

Comment: Note that your code `name = name + names[i];` doesn't not do what you expect it to. Strings are immutable in .NET; your code mostly creates _garbage_ which must later be _collected_. Read up on the `StringBuilder` class

Comment: OK, I used the debugger finally, but I was not any smarter. When I stepped through the IF loop, I saw that "name" variable got the value "Aaron" (last name) but then it was not added to the list. If I understand it well, "continue" statement skipped "nameList.Add" for the last "name", because there was no "space".

Comment: @PeterDuniho , although it looks like homework, this is not the case. I started programming about five weeks ago, and so far I'm enjoying it. I am not taking any classes and sometimes I try to create task for myself, like this one. I did not have experience with the debugger, but I will definitely be using it.

Comment: _"although it looks like homework, this is not the case"_ -- I would disagree. While it may be self-assigned homework, it is an academic exercise nonetheless, and you would benefit more from an academic answer, not a code dump. In any case, whether you consider it homework or not, you _definitely_ need to make an attempt to debug code before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you don't have `' '` after the name "Aaron". You need to do add to the list the name in the last iteration of the for loop if you have a name.

3 Possible solutions:

1. Easy one but not the perfect solution. Add space at the end:

   ```
    string names = "John Martin Sophia Aaron ";
   ```
2. After the first loop add:

   ```
    if (name != string.Empty)
    {
        namesList.Add(name);
    }
   ```
3. Inside the loop over names you can check if it is the last one, if so and name exists, add it to the list:

   ```
    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        if (names[i] != ' ')
        {
            name = name + names[i];

            if (i == names.Length - 1)
            {
                namesList.Add(name);
            }

            continue;
        }

        namesList.Add(name);

        name = "";
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Last word does not end with a `space`, hence last word is not added.

You can just add the name after the loop if it is not empty -

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
{
    namesList.Add(name);
}
```

Final Code -

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CSharp_Shell
{

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string names = "John Martin Sophia Aaron";
            
            
            List<string> namesList = new List<string>();

            string name = "";
            
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                if (names[i] != ' ')
                {
                    name = name + names[i];
                    continue;
                }
            
                    namesList.Add(name);

                    name = "";
            }
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                namesList.Add(name);
            }
            
            foreach(string s in namesList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```